# How Does Laravel define the base paths for files and directories?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel ! and I want to know how does laravel load the base files and folders for example in some MVC frameworks they use like constants something like

```
define("ROOT", dirname(__DIR__));
define("APP", ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app');
```

but I dont see something like this in laravel ? i just see config files as arrays 
and config class to load them ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has [built-in helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#available-methods) that allow you to get absolute path to any directory of Laravel app:

```
app_path()
base_path()
config_path()
database_path()
public_path()
resource_path()
storage_path()
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey ! Where i can find these helper functions in laravel files ? i have searched on github laravel/framework repo but i couldn't find them ?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php